# В какое число следует поставить существительное?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, существительные, перечисление, число

В русском языке можно написать о двух одинаковых объектах, имеющих разные характеристики в одном предложении, например:
"Мне нравятся белая и красная фиалки?\фиалка?"
Но я совершенно запуталась, пытаясь разобраться в постановке числа существительного. Буду очень благодарна, если кто-то откликнется на мой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если фиалки такого цвета вам **вообще нравятся**, то надо записать так: Мне нравятся белые и красные фиалки. (Другой вариант записи: Мне нравятся белые фиалки и красные фиалки.)
2. Если вы делает **выбор в конкретном случае**, то теоретически возможны варианты, поэтому надо посмотреть эту тему у Розенталя:
   [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_08](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)

§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими

Пункт 1. При **обратном порядке** (сказуемое предшествует подлежащим) **обычно** используется форма единственного числа, например: По земле, истомленной в зное, **разливалась** свежесть, прохлада и неизъяснимая легкость... (В.Солоухин).  И у нас как раз обратный порядок слов.

В то же время  указанное положение не носит категорического характера, и **препозитивное** сказуемое может стоять в форме множественного числа, если нужно подчеркнуть **множественность предметов**, например: **Слышатся** кашель и стук (Чехов); Снаружи **были слышны** визг, лай и вой (Арсеньев).

Поэтому мы используем форму мн. числа и в этом случае:

*Мне **нравятся** белая и красная фиалки.*  Мы как бы заранее подчеркиваем, что нам нравятся два цвета, а не один.